# SQL query to do INNER JOIN from two tables of a data base

Tags: java, mysql, inner-join

I have two tables:

1. usuario (user in english): nombre, apellido, usuario, contrasena, id_perfil
2. perfil (profile in english): id_perfil, nombre

I have a login on my program using Java and MySQL and I want to know if the username and password entered by the user is correct, to send him to another Jframe.

I don't know much about SQL query but, I did my best here (I'm passing the username and password directly to the function):

```
public boolean login(String usuario, String contrasena) {
        Dato_login d_lgn = new Dato_login();
        boolean resultado = false;

        sSQL = "SELECT u.nombre, u.apellido, u.usuario, u.contrasena, u.id_perfil, p.nombre AS perfil_nombre FROM "
                + "usuario U INNER JOIN perfil P u.id_perfil = p.id "
                + "WHERE u.usuario='" + usuario + "' AND u.contrasena='" + contrasena + "'";

        // Java 7 try-with-resources
        try (PreparedStatement pstm = con.prepareStatement(sSQL);
             ResultSet rs = pstm.executeQuery(sSQL)) {

            while (rs.next()) {
                if (d_lgn.getContrasena().equals(contrasena)) {
                    resultado = true;
                } else {
                    resultado = false;
                }

                d_lgn.setPerfil(rs.getString("perfil_nombre"));
                d_lgn.setUsuario(rs.getString("usuario"));
                d_lgn.setNombre(rs.getString("nombre"));
                d_lgn.setApellido(rs.getString("apellido"));
                d_lgn.setContrasena(rs.getString("contrasena"));
            }

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "SQLException:\n" + e, "Error: login(String usuario, String contrasena)", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }

        return resultado;
    }
```

Is not working, it keeps telling me that there is not any user to log in.
What I need to change?

Also I would like to receive the name of the profile instead of the id of the user, I tried with INNER JOIN but I don't understand how it works correctly yet.

Table:

[image]

Error received:

> Error in SQL Syntax

Comment: `username` is not `usuario`, and `password` is not `contrasena` is not `d_lgn.getContrasena()`, and why are you joining to `perfil` when you don't use it for anything? You should also change to use `PreparedStatement` with `?` parameter markers, so you code is not susceptible to [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Comment: I use it on another part of my program, I just tried to paste the problem exactly. Why username and password is not correct?, I don't understand the issue, I'm a new pogrammer, can you help me a little bit please?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this part:

```
sSQL = "SELECT u.nombre, u.apellido, u.usuario, u.contrasena, u.id_perfil FROM usuario U INNER JOIN perfil P ON p.nombre=u.nombre WHERE u.usuario='"
                + usuario + "' AND u.contrasena='" + contrasena + "'";
```

I don't see where a variables `contrasena` or `usario` is defined. Should that be `...AND u.usario='" + username + "' AND u.contrasena='" + password + "'";` instead? (putting aside a moment that this exposes a SQL Injection vulnerability). Also, it seems suspect that you're joining your `usario` and `perfil` tables on `nombre`. Is it the case that a User's name would be the same as their Profile name? Without understanding your domain and data model better, I can't really say.

If you also wanted to retrieve the profile name as well, your query could be this:

```
SELECT u.nombre, u.apellido, u.usuario, u.contrasena, p.nombre as perfil_nombre
  FROM usario u
  JOIN perfil p ON u.id_perfil = p.id_perfil
 WHERE u.usuario = ? and u.contrasena = ?
```

Notice I'm joining `usario` and `perfil` on the id columns instead of `nombre`. I think you want the `usario.perfil_id` to match the `perfil.id_perfil` column.

Instead of `con.createStatement()` use `con.createPreparedStatement()`. See [Using Prepared Statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) for more information on that.

Lastly, to access the `perfil.nombre` from the `ResultSet` do this: `rs.getString("perfil_nombre");`

Also I am returning `perfil.nombre` instead of `usario.nombre` because you mentioned your want the profile name instead of the user name.

Comment: I think there is an error on the SQL query here: u.id_perfil = p.id, should be: u.id_perfil = p.nombre, right?. I want to get the name of the profile table instead of the id_profile. you know, to show Pofile: administrator and not Profile: 2

Comment: Everything between `SELECT` and `FROM` is where you're listing the columns you want returned. So if you want to include `perfil.nombre` in the results you need to include it in the `SELECT` clause. That's why I added `p.nombre as perfil_nombre`. This will give you the value of `perfil.nombre` in your `ResultSet` under the key `perfil_nombre`. I gave it that alias so it could be distinguished from `usario.nombre`.  When you do `u.id_perfil = p.id` you are saying to return rows where the value in `u.id_perfil` equals `p.id`. I assume you join the tables on id, rather than by the `nombre` column

Comment: This explains how the different parts of a SQL statement break down and which parts do what: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190617(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Can you post that picture a different way? I'm not sure what that site is. Maybe you can edit your original post and place it in there. Also I don't think your example adds up because I don't see a `usario` or `contrasena` variable defined in your `Java` code. I don't see how it compiles in the first place. Please update your original post to show your latest code and what SQL errors you're running into. Thanks

Comment: Ok. I edited my Answer as well. I think you just need to tweak your query a little to match the table structure you showed. Try this instead `+ "usuario U JOIN perfil P ON u.id_perfil = p.id_perfil `

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129673/discussion-between-c-smith-and-robert-gomez).